# win 10 conflict between NTFS mapped drive and samba (1.0) mapped drive

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, network-shares, samba

i have a win 10 with 2 mapped drives.  one is mapped to another win 10 share drive, and the other to a samba share on Ubuntu server. This setup has worked well for the past 5 years plus.
Last week, i suddenly started loosing my samba share every time i restart or reboot win 10.  So, i have to delete the samba connection and remap it all over again.

After many attempts to fix this, i have found out that if i delete my win 10 mapped drive altogether, then my samba mapped drive works fine.  i could restart/reboot win 10 without any affect on it.

Anybody have an idea how to fix this so both maps can co-exist?

Comment: Maybe a drive letter collision?

Comment: Letter collision is not the issue...i checked, one is on Y the other on Z.  plus if i remap the ntfs drive share when the samba is already mapped, the samba share would stop working.